# Three js texture is not aligned with UV

Tags: three.js, uv-mapping

I am trying to apply texture to exported from blender model with unwraped UV, however the texture is not mapped corretly.

I have exported a UV layot from blender and marked one island in red to check the texture offset

```
gltfLoader.load('v3.glb',
(file) => {
    bowtie_Mesh = file.scene.children.find((child) =>  child.name === 'bowtie003');
    bowtie_Mesh.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('uv 2.png')
    })

    scene.add(bowtie_Mesh)
});
```

[image: The screenshot of the uv offset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in flipped Y axis. Adding texture.flipY = false solves the problem

```
const uvTex = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('uv 2.png')
uvTex.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
uvTex.flipY = false;

gltfLoader.load('v3.glb',
(file) => {
    bowtie_Mesh = file.scene.children.find((child) =>  child.name === 'bowtie003');
    bowtie_Mesh.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: uvTex
    })

    scene.add(bowtie_Mesh)
});
```

Comment: It'd be better if the UV mapping is done correctly on the model itself before exporting from blender instead of fixing it in the code by flipping. Maybe you need to flip the axis while exporting the model from blender.